# MS Outlook - Set up alert showing all events for a day at specific hour

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, events, alert

Right now, an alert is set by default at 15 minutes before an event to show up as a reminder. However, I'd like to have an alert every day in the morning that tells me which events I have today.

Is there a way to set an alarm or event reminder on Outlook (2016) so every day, at 09:00 a.m. (for example), it automatically pops with **all the events** I have scheduled for that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

Reminders are associated with *individual events*. As such, Outlook will display the Reminders window any time an event's configured reminder time arrives. There's no functionality to trigger the Reminders window at a time other than when an event is configured to notify you.

However, you may find that Outlook's Today view does what you need. It will show you all appointments on your calendar for the day (regardless of whether a reminder is set for them).

To access the Today view, click your account name near the top of the folder pane in Outlook.